# Firebase loginWithFacebook is not returning enough info in FAuthData (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

according to the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/facebook.html), if i use this code:

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: {
    (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

    if facebookError != nil {
        println("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
    } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
        println("Facebook login was cancelled.")
    } else {
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

        ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
            withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Login failed. \(error)")
                } else {
                    println("Logged in! \(authData)")
                }
        })
    }
})
```

then i should get back FAuthData object with the following info:

[image]

but all i get back when I print authData is:

```
print \(authData)

AuthData facebook:1249012401249012
```

where the number is the facebook user's ID number.

How can I get more info back? I want to use the info to create a user in Firebase. with a unique uid and full name and email

Comment: Are you sure the data isn't there? Have you tried `print(authData.providerData)`?

Comment: doh! thank you for pointing that out. I was string interpolating authData (in fairness the Firebase article did that and I copied it) so I wasn't seeing any data. your suggestion fixed my problem, I am getting data

Answer (score 2):

Try `print(authData.providerData)` instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11469362)

Comment: @mustaccio Did you read the question and comments above? It exactly answers the question.